# group email limit exceeded on my script

Tags: email, scripting, google-sheets

I started an email list on google sheets for some guys in my area to sign up for basketball twice a week.  I want to send a group email to the entire list twice a week.  The email will not send because I get the following error message:

3/14/17 10:53 AM    emailTuesday    Limit Exceeded: Email Recipients Per Message. (line 34, file "Code")    time-based  3/14/17 10:53 AM

There are 75 people on the list.  In all my research I've found that even the lowest level accounts can send 100 emails per day.  Other than this list, I don't send many emails so I know I'm not exceeding that limit.  In fact, I have been manually sending the email in the meanwhile since it is not currently working. My script is below:

```
    function emailWednesday(){
      var emaillistsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('FridayEmailList');
      var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
      var numRows = 90;   // Number of rows to process
      var dataRange = emaillistsheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1)
      // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
      var data = dataRange.getValues();
      var emailAddress = data;  // First column
      var message = "message";
      var subject = "subject";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
```

Comment: There is a 50 recipients per email limit, per the [Quotas page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).  Are you trying to send to all 75 at one time?  You could either make a [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/) and send to that if you want everyone to be able to Reply All, etc.  Or loop through the code and send to one recipient or small groups of recipients at a time.

Comment: So if I use a Google Group it will work?  I want people to be able to reply all.  How do I send to the group?

Comment: When you create the group it will get an email address.  Reply methods and capabilities will depend on how you set up the group.  See the link in my first comment for creating a group.